# nginx, docker, and static content

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx

I'm serving wordpress for most urls, and static content for a lot of legacy content. Everything under one domain name. Wordpress is served out of docker, via a proxy pass. Static files are just from a unique root.

```
location @docker {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8007;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding  "";
    proxy_set_header    Proxy "";
}   


location / {
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/maritime_static_site.conf;
    root /mnt/code/maritime/maritime-static;
    #try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri/index.htm $uri/index.php @docker;

    try_files $uri @docker;

    auth_basic "Private Beta";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd-maritime;
}

location ~ \.php$ {

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Static html, static php, and images are working. Wordpress is working. Wordpress admin (/wp-admin & wp-login.php) are giving file not found. I'm guessing it's trying files from the static root location. Any ideas how I can fix this?